# How to make true_fn of tf.cond skip a for loop in tensorflow v1.0/python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use `tf.cond` to mimic the python `if-else` logic in the `_preprocessing_fn` of `transform.py`.

Specifically, if the condition of `tf.cond` is true, I want to skip the current iteration of the for loop.

This seems problematic because `true_fn` and `false_fn` parameters of `tf.cond` are expected to return Tensors according to the documentation.

However, in my case, I want `true_fn` (aka `skip_feature_fn`)to simply "continue" to the next for loop iteration. Also, I want `false_fn` to take in two inputs (`feature` and `sp`) and simply feed them to some other API (e.g. `tft.vocabulary`).
I don't expect either of `true_fn` or `false_fn` to return anything.

Could someone help me accomplish my goal?

Here is the code snippet I'm working with:

```
def _preprocessing_fn(inputs, category_features=features.STRING_FEATURES):
  outputs = transform_lib.preprocessing_helper_fn(
      inputs, used_features=category_features)

  for feature in category_features:
    if feature:
      sp = outputs[feature]
      tf.cond(
          tf.equal(sp.dense_shape[1], 0), skip_feature_fn, lambda: process_feature_further(
              feature,
              sp,
          ))

  return outputs
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use `python` code so that the [AutoGraph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/control_flow.md) can rewrite it. I believe you can have more control in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, my code is written in tensorflow v1.0 and it looks like AutoGraph is only supported in tensofrflow v2.0?